# OBIEE chained prompt doesn't work

Tags: variables, prompt, obiee, presentation, chained

I have three fields in a Dashboard Prompt: Carrier, Region, End Period. I want to only show the existing Region. I want to chain Region to Carrier.

I try to do that by making Carrier a Presentation Variable and by using it in the Region Prompt options in the following way:

```
SELECT "REGIONS"."REGION"   
FROM "Special_Coverage"."CARRIER","Special_Coverage"."DETAIL SPECIAL COV FACTS","Special_Coverage"."REGIONS"  
WHERE  "Special_Coverage"."CARRIER"."NAME CARRIER"= ('@{CAR}') FETCH FIRST 65001 ROWS ONLY
```

But the query doesn’t take the value of the Carrier and doesn’t filter.

Comment: You won't get a different answer in here than on the OTN forums...

Comment: Why not use the "Limit values by" option?